# Does applying pressure on both sides of your head damage brain cells?

Tags: brain

Someone squeezed my head with her hands. I am concerned whether it has caused any damage like loss of brain cells.

Comment: [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [How To Ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [meta]. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Answer (score 2):

If someone squeezed your head hard enough to cause brain damage, that means they squeezed your head hard enough to fracture your skull. I assure you that you would know without doubt if they squeezed that hard.

Your brain is fine.

Comment: I am more concerned if i lost any brain cells. There are no bad effects I feel right now but might it have caused loss of brain cells that will affect me later in the future?

Comment: How would you lose brain cells? Your brain is encased in and protected by your skull, and your skull cannot be compressed unless it's compressed so much that it fractures. That is the only way you could have lost brain cells, and as I said, you would know without doubt if you had fractured your skull.

Comment: You can lose brain cells without fracturing your skull. For example even small bumps can cause loss of brain cells.

Comment: It is true that banging your head hard enough can knock the brain against the side of your skull and cause some level of brain damage, but that has nothing to do with the situation you described of squeezing.  There is no possibility of you having had brain damage from that.